# pingのタイムアウトオプション

Tags: linux, network

pingのオプションについて

```
ping
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
```

上記から `-W timeout` のオプションをつけることでpingのタイムアウトの時間を変更できると考えています。

```
ping -c 1 -W 10 IPアドレス
```

上記でpingが通る場合は以下の結果がすぐ戻ってくるので良いのですが、

```
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

pingが通らない場合、以下の結果が10秒後に戻ってくる認識だったのですが、2秒～3秒で以下の結果が戻ってきます。
Wコマンドはタイムアウトの値ではないのでしょうか？（使用方法が異なりますか？）

```
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

また `-W` のオプションを10→3とすると、結果が異なるのですが、何か理由があるのでしょうか？

**`-W 10` の場合**

```
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

**`-W 3` の場合**

```
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

■追記
wakuwakuさまのコメントを受け以下を試してみました。
●成功

```
date;/bin/ping -c 1 -W 60 192.168.xxx.xxx;date★適当なIPアドレス
2019年  9月 30日 月曜日 16:16:44 JST
PING 192.168.xxx.xxx (192.168.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.xxx.xxx ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

2019年  9月 30日 月曜日 16:17:44 JST★60秒後にタイムアウトしている
```

●失敗

```
date;/bin/ping -c 1 -W 60 172.16.yyy.yyy ;date★実際に存在する機器のケーブルを抜いた
2019年  9月 30日 月曜日 16:17:53 JST
PING 172.16.yyy.yyy (172.16.yyy.yyy) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.zzz.zzz icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable★前者には出ていなかったログ

--- 172.16.zzz.zzz ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

2019年  9月 30日 月曜日 16:17:56 JST★3秒後にタイムアウトとなっている
```

Comment: OSやpingのバージョン等によって微妙に実装が異なる場合があるので、実行環境も念のため記載しておくとよいかもしれません。

Comment: cubick♦さま。コメントありがとうございます。Redhat7.4となります。pingのバージョンとはどのようにしべたらよいのでしょうか？

Comment: WSL(Win10)のUbuntuで確認したところ上記のエラーが起こりませんでした。推測ですが、NW経路のどこか（スイッチなど）がタイムアウトエラーを返していたりしないでしょうか？スイッチを介さない環境などがありましたら、切り分けできるかもしれません。

Comment: wakuwakuさま。コメントありがとうございます。こちらでも試してみました。（追記しますた）NW経路が関係するかもしれませんね

Comment: 同一セグメントの場合はエラーが返ってくるのは「172.16.yyy.yyy」を「172.16.zzz.zzz」が判定可能だからだと思います。「192.168.xxx.xxx」の場合は「172.16.zzz.zzz」がエラー判定できてないのかもしれません。（セグメントが違うため？）。お試しいただいたのにお力添えできず申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pingの送信先が同一セグメントにある場合、送信元マシンでarpリクエストのタイムアウトが先に検出されるため、送信エラーになる可能性があります。(※3秒だとこの可能性が高いと予想します)

＃この場合、ICMP ECHO Requestパケットは送出されないはずです。

また、pingの送信先が異なるセグメントにある場合でも、NW装置が「Destination Host Unreachable」等のICMPエラーを返してきても、pingの応答タイムアウト前にエラー判定されると思います。

詳しく調べるのであれば、パケットキャプチャして、ICMP ECHO Requestが創出されているか、エラーが返ってきてないか調べるのがよいと思います。